# Quarkus Session is NULL

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to use Session in my Application but if I want to get the Session Id from the routingcontext this Session Id will be NULL and I will get the following error:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.vertx.ext.web.Session.data()" because the return value of "io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext.session()" is null
```

my code:

```
    ...
    RoutingContext routingContext;

    public CallbackResource(@Context RoutingContext ctx){
        this.routingContext = ctx;
    }
    ...

    public Response callback() {
        logger.infof("session id %s", routingContext.session().id());
    }
    ...
```

The Session support at the application will work out of the box, or am I missing some dependencies or some implementations?

Thank you very much for helping.
Cheers
joeng

Comment: Session is not supported out of the box. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Im want to store some user related data of an authenticated user in the session without database and also jwt tokens tenant specific (refresh / access tokens)  for other REST backend calls.

Comment: Is any "data store" available which is related to quarkus q_session?

Comment: There is not any such thing